# IntelliJ IDEA - adding multiple frameworks in one project

Tags: intellij-idea

When I create a new static web project, I can select whether I want it to be a Bootstrap project, HTML5 Boilerplate project, AngularJS project etc.

How can I create an empty project with more than one of these? I'd like to work with both AngularJS and Bootstrap at once.